# Python + sqlite3: executemany with "constructed" values

Tags: python, sqlite, executemany

I'm trying to use `executemany` in Python to populate some rows.

However, I'm getting:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: 3 values for 4 columns
```

I understand that in general, you use `executemany` to stuff raw values into the DB as efficiently as possible, and with that in mind, you generally want the number of values inserted to match the number of columns.

But what if one or more of the columns are "constructed" via SQL, and do not have any corresponding input value?

Small example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
import os
import sys
import sqlite3
from contextlib import closing

DB_FILE = 'test.sqlite'

with closing(sqlite3.connect(DB_FILE)) as db:

    # First, some setup...
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE test (id TEXT PRIMARY KEY, a TEXT, b TEXT, c TEXT)')

    sql = '''INSERT INTO test (id, a, b, c) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)'''

    data = []
    for i in range(5):
        idStr = str(i)
        data.append( (idStr, 'a{}'.format(i), 'b{}'.format(i), 'c{}'.format(i)) )

    cursor.executemany(sql, data)

    # Now, to exercise the problem:
    # This does an 'upsert', but the same problem could occur in
    # other circumstances.

    sql = '''
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO test (id, a, b, c)
VALUES (
    ?,
    (SELECT a,b FROM test WHERE id = ?),
    ?
)'''

    data = []
    for i in range(3,7):
        idStr = str(i)
        data.append( (idStr, idStr, 'c{}'.format(i)) )

    cursor.executemany(sql, data)

    db.commit()
```

When you run that, you get the error mentioned at the top (`3 values for 4 columns`).

I suppose I could work around this by breaking the `SELECT a,b` into separate `SELECT a..., SELECT b...` parts, but is there a better way?

The example given is small — in reality, it might be 10 columns that I'll now have to verbosely list with their own `(SELECT ...)` clauses.

---

**UPDATE 1** This is not specific to `executemany`, as I had originally thought. Even running the plain SQL by hand has the same problem.

**UPDATE 2** The answers below suggest using a `SELECT` rather than `VALUES`, however, this does no work when a new row is being added (as in my "upsert" case), since the `SELECT` returns no rows in that case.

Answer (score 4):

You SQL requires 4 params into VALUES. The Problem is that SQLite is not able to return multiple values into a subquery, you will run into the following error:
sqlite3.OperationalError: only a single result allowed for a SELECT that is part of an expression

What you can do is to use 2 Select statements, one for each of the value you require. Here is what I tried:

```
sql = '''
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO test (id, a, b, c)
VALUES (
    ?,
    (SELECT a FROM test WHERE id = ?),
    (SELECT b FROM test WHERE id = ?),
    ?
)'''
```

There is also a more elegant solution for this.

```
sql = '''
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO test (id, a, b, c)
SELECT
    ?, a, b, ?
FROM test WHERE id = ?
'''
```

Here is a working example, i made some changes so the database table get populated accordingly:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
import os
import sys
import sqlite3
from contextlib import closing

DB_FILE = 'test.sqlite'

with closing(sqlite3.connect(DB_FILE)) as db:

    # First, some setup...
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE test (id TEXT PRIMARY KEY, a TEXT, b TEXT, c TEXT)')

    sql = '''INSERT INTO test (id, a, b, c) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)'''

    data = []
    for i in range(5):
        idStr = str(i)
        data.append( (idStr, 'a{}'.format(i), 'b{}'.format(i), 'c{}'.format(i)) )

    cursor.executemany(sql, data)

    sql = '''
    INSERT OR REPLACE INTO test (id, a, b, c)
    SELECT
        ?, a, b, ?
    FROM test WHERE id = ?
    '''

    data = []
    for i in range(4, 7):
        data.append((i, 'c{}'.format(i), i - 3))

    cursor.executemany(sql, data)

    db.commit()
```

**Update 1**

If you need Default values in case the select returns nothing you can use this:

```
sql = '''
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO test (id, a, b, c)
VALUES (
    ?,
    (SELECT ifnull((SELECT a FROM test WHERE id = ?), 'Default 1')),
    (SELECT ifnull((SELECT b FROM test WHERE id = ?), 'Default 2')),
    ?
)'''

data = []
for i in range(4, 10):
    data.append((i, i, i, 'c{}'.format(i)))
```

Comment: Hmm, after trying this more, I am having some trouble… the INSERT-OR-REPLACE is not doing the INSERT in the case where thd `id` does not match.  I wonder - why did you add `i-3` for the final data?

Comment: This is just to match some of the ids of the entries done with the first statement so the new entries are not getting null values on the *a* and *b* columns.

Comment: But if I *do* want NULLs in the a and b columns (or some other placeholder value), it is not achievable like this, right? I mean, that is not just putting some values in place, it's also the reason that the `INSERT` happens at all.

Comment: Using this will allow you to have inserts with null values where the select is not returning anything:

Comment: `
sql = '''
    INSERT OR REPLACE INTO test (id, a, b, c)
    VALUES (
        ?,
        (SELECT a FROM test WHERE id = ?),
        (SELECT b FROM test WHERE id = ?),
        ?
    )'''

    data = []
    for i in range(4, 10):
        data.append((i, i, i, 'c{}'.format(i)))
`

Comment: Exactly — this is the `VALUES` version that I was trying to avoid in the first place. See the "I suppose I could work around this …" bit in the original question.  It seems like maybe the ultimate answer is "No, there is not a better way."  Though I'd love to be proven wrong (:

Comment: I made an update in my original answer, so you can also set defaults. I don't think you will get around with this another way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! There is a better way!  Replace your `VALUES` clause with a `SELECT` statement!

The query will look like:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO test (id, a, b, c)
    SELECT ?, a, b, ? FROM test WHERE id = ?
```

Remember to change your `data` list because the parameters are in a different order now.

Comment: Note: I removed parens around the SELECT since it seems to be invalid syntax.

Comment: It looks like this doesn't actually work, in the case where it is a new ID (the `INSERT` side of `INSERT OR REPLACE`. Is that right? If so, it doesn't work for my case.